# Show that in a discrete space if a map $f:X\to X$ is homotopic to the identity map $I_X:X \to X$ , then $f=I_X$.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a discrete space. Show that if a map $f:X\to X$ is homotopic to the identity map $I_X:X \to X$ , then $f=I_X$.

---

How can I able to solve this? Can someone help me please?I am new to this subject.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Do you have any thoughts or have tried anything you can share? it really helps responders to understand where your current level is. Regards

Answer (score 3):

Let $h_t(x)\colon \mathbb I\times X\to X$ be a homotopy $f\to I_X$. For any $x\in X$, $h_-(x)\colon \mathbb I\to X$ is a path in $X$, so in particular $h_0(x) = f(x)$ and $h_1(x) = x$ lie in the same path component. What are the path components of a discrete space?

Comment: It's just a point!